# error while running ruby application at system startup in ubuntu

Tags: scripts, ruby, rails, rvm

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Have a script file which runs when entered manually in terminal

```
gnome-terminal -e /home/precise/Desktop/cartodb/script.sh
```

The content of script file is

```
cd /home/ubuntupc/Desktop/cartodb20/
sh /home/ubuntupc/.rvm/scripts/rvm
bundle exec foreman start -p 3000
```

So what i  tried to do is to run this script at every system start up. So on Startup Applications

```
command: gnome-terminal -e /home/precise/Desktop/cartodb/script.sh
```

On terminal Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command

```
Checked the "Run command as a login shell"
```

But this seems to be not working. When restarted the machine found these error in terminal

```
The child process exited normally with status 127.
ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use ruby` first.
```

Some info regarding the installed packages and system.

**$ which ruby**

```
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
```

**$ which rails**

```
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rails
```

**$ which gem**

```
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/gem
```

**$ cat ~/.bash_profile**

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

**$ which -a ruby**

```
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
```

**$ sudo update-alternatives --config ruby**

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for ruby.
```

**$ sudo find / -name "rubygems" -print**

```
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/test/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/test/rubygems/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/doc/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.1/lib/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.1/test/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.1/test/rubygems/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/functions/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/scripts/functions/rubygems
/home/ubuntupc/.rvm/scripts/rubygems
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/test/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/test/rubygems/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/doc/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.0/lib/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.0/test/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.0/test/rubygems/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/scripts/functions/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/rubygems
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rubygems
```

Please point out what i am missing as i am new to the ruby applications.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does

```
sh /home/ubuntupc/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Which will run rvm with no arguments. What you actually want to do is to include the rvm code in your current script, so replace that line with

```
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Comment: That solved. Now it works fine.